# Standby archive deletion

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, disaster-recovery, standby

I have a primary database with a standby in data guard configuration running in a RHEL host. Thing is the storage assigned to this DR is very less, meaning the archive logs file system gets full in no-time.

Now is it possible to automate deletion of archives from standby database once archives are applied to the standby??

```
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO APPLIED ON ALL STANDBY
```

The above command will work if I need to delete archives from Primary.

What can be done on standby? Im not in a situation to add more storage at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The same can be specified in the standby database.

[RMAN Configurations at a Standby Where Backups Are Not Performed](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/rman.htm#SBYDB4856)

> The following RMAN configurations are recommended at a standby
>   database where backups are not done:
>
> 1. Connect RMAN to the standby database as target, and to the recovery catalog.
> 2. Enable automatic deletion of archived logs once they are applied at the standby database:

```
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO APPLIED ON ALL STANDBY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure both databases to put the Archived Redo Logs into the FRA (and nowhere else; you'll have copies on both the primary and the standby hosts so you shouldn't need any *more* copies of them).

Oracle Database will automatically manage [all] the files in the FRA, *including* deleting archivelogs that are no longer required.

Regards,   Phill  W.